# passing variables from form to update but url doesnt shows the value for it

Tags: php

i'm passing variables through url to function but it not reflect anything
here is the code for url:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/service/service.php?action=update_details&id=$id,&name=$name,&lname=$lname,&email=$email,&username=$username,&password=$password,&gender=$gender,&mobile=$mobile,&address=$address');
```

and function is on other php file. Here is code:

```
if($tag == 'update_details') {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $name=($_GET['name']);      
    $lname=($_GET['lname']);
    $gender=($_GET['gender']);
    $email=($_GET['email']);    
    $username=($_GET['username']);   
    $password=($_GET['password']);  
    $mobile=($_GET['mobile']);
    $address=($_GET['address']);
    if  ->updateUser($id,$name,$lname,$username,$password,$gender,$email,$mobile,$address)) {
        $app_info = "success";
        exit (json_encode($app_info));
    } else {
        $error="not done";  
        exit(json_encode($error));  
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use double quotes, not single or else your variables will no be variables anymore..

Comment: added double quotes but don't gave result

Comment: This should be giving you an error: `if  ->updateUser`

Comment: Put at the very top of your page `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` See if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma from url:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/service/service.php?action=update_details&id=$id&name=$name&lname=$lname&email=$email&username=$username&password=$password&gender=$gender&mobile=$mobile&address=$address');
```

Comment: removed it but no result

Answer (score 0):

First you must take in account all the advices you already got:

- replace simple quotes by double quotes (as noticed by @Rasclatt), in order to have your embedded variables interpreded
- suppress commas (as already by @Jayesh Chitroda) to get a normally built url

Then in addition you must take care of this [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) advice :

> If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

So if some of your variables may contain such characters (which is likely expected in your case) you must also `urlencode()` them.
*Remember: don't `urlencode()` the whole URI, but each involved variable.*

This way you will correctly invoke your `service.php` script, but there is yet another potential issue (also already noticed by @Rasclatt): `if  ->updateUser(...)){` has no sense.
Maybe it's a typo in your question? It's now up to you to examine this point.